# Can you "Create a new download URL" in Firebase Storage programmatically?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

[image]

In Firebase Storage console, you are able to generate a new **download url**

.. via that small gray link at the bottom of the image

Can this ***Reset URL Event*** be triggered programmatically via Google Cloud Functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no public API for this.  Please feel free to [file a feature request](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) stating your specific use case.